Jetpack compose - Implementing a Complex Filtering System with Deep Links in an E-Commerce App
For the past few days I have been trying to solve a problem that does not let me sleep...
I’m trying to implement a filtering system in an e-commerce application. Let’s assume that on Screen A, I have a list of items that can be filtered using various criteria, for example: price range, type, condition, brand, etc. There are a lot of filters, just like in a comprehensive online store application. Of course, the list is filtered and returned by the server, not locally. Filters can be selected on a dedicated Screen B, which is accessed after clicking the filter button on Screen A.
Up to now, this system has been based on a shared ViewModel for both Screen A and Screen B. However, the application should also support a deep link system. When opening a shared search link, the application should open the item list screen with the filters applied.
I’m out of ideas and patience for how to implement this properly. How should Screen A and Screen B communicate with each other, and how can I integrate deep links into all of this?
Tech stack: Jetpack compose, compose ui, compose navigation, retrofit, hilt.
I’m begging for your help!

I'd keep the communication same (shared ViewModel). The deeplink will open ScreenA, you'll parse the filters from the deeplink and set them to the viewmodel and that should be it, no?

@JanBína I think you’re right, but isn’t it a problem that such a large amount of data is passed through deep links? Even lists of IDs can be passed as a filter. I wouldn’t want to use Parcelable, so should filters like lists or doubles be passed as a string type? I’m using type-safe navigation.

I don't think it is a problem, the whole navigation component is build around passing arguments in a form of url

Ok, I will test the solution and let you know if it works. Thank you for your answer :D

@JanBína If possible, I have one more question. My application uses two NavHosts. One main one – the root, and the other, which is placed in HomeScreen to make everything work correctly with BottomNavigation. I added a deep link to one of the screens in the second NavHost, not in the root NavHost. The deep link always redirects me to the startDestination of that NavHost, not to the target screen. Is it possible to use deep links correctly with multiple NavHosts?
